# Why didn’t you wake me up? I’ve been up since 5:00 that’s not my responsibility!

Tags: single-word-requests

you’re in a Long term relationship with someone and they always say things like “ I don’t care those are Your problems” or “ that’s not my responsibility” “ I’m helping you out”. How would you describe an attitude as such. They’re self centered as it is so it would be something along the lines of that I’m just not sure of the exact word. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for **[egocentric](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/egocentric)**?

From Dictionary.com:

> *adjective*
>
> 1. having or regarding the self or the individual as the center of all things:
>      *an egocentric philosophy that ignores social causes.*
> 2. having little or no regard for interests, beliefs, or attitudes other than one's own; self-centered: *an egocentric person; egocentric demands upon the time and patience of others.*